# Android App That Launches Voice Assistant

Tags: android

I would like an app on the my Android home screen to launch voice assistant.

Preferrably it activates whatever the default assistant is or let's me select it from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Assistant app in the play store does this.  I'm not sure how long the google app supported this but it does.